# Post got moved to Wordpress and then immediately voted as off-topic

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, migrated-questions, wordpress-se

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50691/creating-php-counter-rules-for-wordpress-loop

What am I meant to do? Do I re-word my post and get it back up there? Totally baffled.

Comment: As I type it looks like it's been re-opened.